Deserialize JSON(not in an array) with C# and write to a SQL table
Would like some help in parsing the JSON and insert (or at least output the key value pairs) without a specific class/object.
JSON string (portion):
{
"message": "Success",
"data": {
    "100": {
        "Type": "Solid",
        "Name": "Sphere",
         
    },
    "101": {
        "Type": "Solid",
        "Name": "Cube",
    },
    "102": {
        "Type": "Solid",
        "Name": "Cylinder",
    }
},
"Error": []
}

I want to be able to get value like:



ID
Type
Name




100
Solid
Sphere


102
Solid
Cube


103
Solid
Cylinder



My code:
var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var flattened = jObject.Flatten();

foreach (var item in flattened)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " ### " + item.Value);
}

var flattenedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flattened, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(flattenedJsonString);

But I am not getting clean values as I desire. Any help? Thanks.

I don't see any code that gets the value of the data JSON property.

What exactly is .Flatten()? Which library does it come from? "I am not getting clean values as I desire" could you tell us what that is? Please don't just assume we know what you're talking about. See [ask] and edit your post with a [mre].

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); var flattened = from property in JObject.Parse(json)["data"].Properties let nested = properly.Value select new { Id = e property.Key, Type = nested.Get<string>("Type"), Value = nested.Get<string>("Value") }; return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flattened);

Side note: ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult() doen't ever do this. Use await instead.

@gunr2171 -- Flatten is from JsonFlatten NuGet

You want to flatten the objects in the data into list of objects.

Select data object from the JSON.
Convert it to Dictionary<string, JObject>.
With System.Linq to iterate each Value element, adding the ID key into the JObject and return it.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var flattened = jObject.SelectToken("data")
    .ToObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>()
    .Select(x =>
            {
                JObject jObj = x.Value;
                jObj.Add("Id", x.Key);
                        
                return jObj;
            })
    .ToList();


Demo @ .NET Fiddle

SelectToken - one for the toolbox!

@YongShun -- Thank you. In order for me to extract the values to insert it into a sql table, can I loop through like below or is there a better way? foreach (var item in flattened)
{
Console.WriteLine(item.SelectToken("Id"));
Console.WriteLine(item.SelectToken("Type"));
Console.WriteLine(item.SelectToken("Name"));
}

Hi @user7481254, yes, you can achieve grabbing those properties via .SelectToken(). Alternatively, you can cast (deserialize) those JObjects with the model class as this demo.
